# Grok DistributionNotFound: grokcore.startup

Tags: python, linux, paster, grok

Used `grokproject Sample` as in the grok homepage tutorial to simultaneously create a new project and install the grok framework.

`cd Sample` then ran `bin/paster serve parts/etc/deploy.ini` as in tutorial and came back with a `DistributionNotFound: grokcore.startup` error

traceback @ http://pastebin.com/T01J0ndM

An educated guess tells me the grok package was not installed with grokproject command?

Using Gentoo Linux.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error arose because I moved my project from the original install directory. Obviously there must be location dependent config settings that I can't find.

Creating a new project from scratch in the new directory solved the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Normally, when you move a project, running

```
$ python bootstrap.py
$ ./bin/buildout
```

in the *new* location should regenerate all local paths in scripts and config files. It will also download and install eggs needed (like grokcore.startup) if they are not in a commonly shared place like the standard pythons site-packages dir or a common eggs-directory (see below).

You can tell buildout to install your eggs at the same location everytime by creating in your home dir a `.buildout/` directory and in this directory a file called `default.cfg` with contents like this:

```
[buildout]
eggs-directory = /home/myname/.buildout/eggs
```

which would install all 'local' eggs in the given path.